# Exclusions of rows after applying "Display.max_rows"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical-clustering

I have a dataframe which has 50k rows. I was working on a clustering model and created a cluster groups with this command;

```
# Create clusters groups
cluster_labels = cut_tree(mergings, n_clusters=3).reshape(-1, )
cluster_labels
```

later used pd.set_option to assign the cluster labels,

```
# assign cluster labels
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
rfm['cluster_labels'] = cluster_labels
rfm.shape
```

after performing above, there's about 200 rows are missing from the actual df.

Before using the dandogram to find the optimal clusters, I've scaled the features, and removed outliers. not sure if it was due to which I am missing those records.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for the support!

Comment: `I've scaled the features, and removed outliers. not sure if it was due to which I am missing those records.`  So for testing not remove `outliers` and check if not missing rows finally.

Comment: yes. i did that. Didnt remove the outliers. now i m getting those missing rows back in my. But the cluster size are skewed to a specific cluster label. how to treat that. not sure